# Unity new Input System returns zero when accessing touch position on first call

Tags: unity-game-engine, input, touch

This is slice of my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
 
 public class Swipe : MonoBehaviour
 {
     InputMaster input;
 
     Vector2 startPos;
 
     void Awake()
     {
         input = new InputMaster();
         input.Enable();
     }
 
     void Start()
     {
         input.Touch.Tap.performed += ctx => CachePosition();
     }
 
     void CachePosition()
     {
         startPos = input.Touch.Position.ReadValue<Vector2>();
         print(startPos)  // !prints  "(0,0)" on first call and then prints appropriate values.
     }
 }
```

What I'm trying to accomplish here is to cache screen position of tap on tap (event). And it works fine from the second call onwards. But on the first call it returns Vector.zero (0,0). I don't get what the problem might be caused by, I'll try to leave any releavant information here. These 2 input actions has no interactions or processors.

"Tap" action is button bind to "Primary Touch/Tap [Touchscreen]".

"Position" action is of type "value" - "Vector2" and pretty self explainatory bind to "Position [Touchscreen]".

Comment: Same problem on different projects, very annoying :(

Comment: having the same issue as well, i'd love to see if anyone has a solution yet

Answer (score 1):

The code below is simply telling the program to wait until the end of the frame (allowing the Input system's touch to do what it does) before calling the cache function. This will help users who fell into the trap of trying Input System.

```
public class Swipe : MonoBehaviour
{
    InputMaster input;

    Vector2 startPos;
    bool firstTouch = true;
    void Awake()
    {
        input = new InputMaster();
        input.Enable();
    }

    void Start()
    {
        input.Touch.Tap.performed += ctx => CachePosition();
    }

    void CachePosition()
    {
        if (firstTouch)
        {
            firstTouch = false;
            StartCoroutine(FirstTouchWait());
        }
        else
        {
            startPos = input.Touch.Position.ReadValue<Vector2>();
            print(startPos);  // !prints  "(0,0)" on first call and then prints appropriate values.
        }
     }

    IEnumerator FirstTouchWait()
    {
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        CachePosition();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the controlType of your action Primary Touch Tap which is now in button to **"Touch"** type. Also add a press interaction of PressOnly behaviour.

So, I was struck at the same error. Although I do not yet completely understand the concept of new input system, this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, seems that New Input System is really bugged. The only thing that worked for me is adding a 0.05 seconds delay before reading input. Really annoying... Not the best solution sure, but it works perfectly.

```
void Start()
{
    touchInput.Touch.PrimaryContact.started += ctx => StartCoroutine(StartRoutine(ctx));
    touchInput.Touch.PrimaryContact.canceled += ctx => EndTouchPrimary(ctx);

}

private IEnumerator StartRoutine(InputAction.CallbackContext context){
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.05f);
    StartTouchPrimary(context);
}

private void StartTouchPrimary(InputAction.CallbackContext context){
    if(OnStartTouch != null) OnStartTouch(Utils.ScreenToWorld(mainCamera, touchInput.Touch.PrimaryPosition.ReadValue<Vector2>()), (float)context.startTime, mainCamera.transform.position);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When TouchContact is started its in phase "Began"
Read TouchStartPos instead of TouchPos
TouchPos returns relevant value only on phase "Moved"

Comment: This is not the problem. This code works, just not on the FIRST input in the game. It does the same with Touchscreen/StartPosition, first input is always (0,0)